# nextcloud issue : duplicate upstream "php-handler"

Tags: php, bash, nginx, nextcloud

I'm actually facing an issue with my Nextcloud server on Nginx who doesn't want to start.

I installed Nextcloud as mentionned in the official documentation :
https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/15/admin_manual/installation/nginx.html

But when I start the service :

> - nginx: [emerg] duplicate upstream
>     "php-handler" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/nextcloud.conf:1 févr. 15
> - nginx: configuration file
>     /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
> - nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1

I tried to re-install properly php-fpm but it still does not work.

Could someone help me ?
Thanks.

Comment: Check `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` for other files - maybe backup files? Use `nginx -T` to see what files Nginx is reading into its configuration, because you have two lines containing `upstream "php-handler"`, and there can be only one.

Answer (score 3):

if you configuration more than one website edited site1.conf and site2.conf on the path.

**Step 1 :**

```
vi /etc/nginx/sites-available/site1.conf
vi /etc/nginx/sites-available/site2.conf
```

and comment this block :

```
#upstream php-handler {
#   server 127.0.0.1:9000;
#}
```

**Step 2 :**
Edit this path :

```
vi /etc/nginx/conf.d/php-fpm.conf
```

and set this value :

```
upstream php-fpm {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

and restart php-fpm & nginx service.